# Finding Friend of Friend in a Dictionary using Levenshtein distance

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, puzzle, bk-tree

Following is what I am trying to do.
Two words `W1` and `W2` are friends if the `Levenshtein distance` for those words are 1.
I am supposed to find all the friend of friend also. I tried to do the same thing with Bk-Tree. It works for small size dictionary ( dictionary only contain one word per line )
but For bigger dictionary it is slowing down heavily and runs for more than a hour still no result.

Following is my code so far

---

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <fstream>  
#include <iostream>  
#include <algorithm>

class BkTree {
    public:
        BkTree();
        ~BkTree();
        void insert(std::string m_item);
        void get_friends(std::string center, std::deque<std::string>& friends);
    private:
        size_t EditDistance( const std::string &s, const std::string &t );
        struct Node {
            std::string m_item;
            size_t m_distToParent;
            Node *m_firstChild;
            Node *m_nextSibling;
            Node(std::string x, size_t dist);        
            bool visited;
            ~Node();
        };
        Node *m_root;
        int   m_size;
    protected:
};

BkTree::BkTree() {
    m_root = NULL; 
    m_size = 0;
}

BkTree::~BkTree() { 
    if( m_root ) 
        delete m_root; 
}

BkTree::Node::Node(std::string x, size_t dist) {
    m_item         = x;
    m_distToParent = dist;
    m_firstChild   = m_nextSibling = NULL;
    visited        = false;
}

BkTree::Node::~Node() {
    if( m_firstChild ) 
        delete m_firstChild;
    if( m_nextSibling ) 
        delete m_nextSibling;
}

void BkTree::insert(std::string m_item) {
    if( !m_root ){
        m_size = 1;
        m_root = new Node(m_item, -1);
        return;
    }
    Node *t = m_root;
    while( true ) {
        size_t d = EditDistance( t->m_item, m_item );
        if( !d ) 
            return;
        Node *ch = t->m_firstChild;
        while( ch ) {
            if( ch->m_distToParent == d ) { 
                t = ch; 
                break; 
            }
            ch = ch->m_nextSibling;
        }
        if( !ch ) {
            Node *newChild = new Node(m_item, d);
            newChild->m_nextSibling = t->m_firstChild;
            t->m_firstChild = newChild;
            m_size++;
            break;
        }
    }
}

size_t BkTree::EditDistance( const std::string &left, const std::string &right ) {
    size_t asize = left.size();
    size_t bsize = right.size();
    std::vector<size_t> prevrow(bsize+1);
    std::vector<size_t> thisrow(bsize+1);

    for(size_t i = 0; i <= bsize; i++)
        prevrow[i] = i;

    for(size_t i = 1; i <= asize; i ++) {
        thisrow[0] = i;
        for(size_t j = 1; j <= bsize; j++) {
            thisrow[j] = std::min(prevrow[j-1] + size_t(left[i-1] != right[j-1]), 
                    1 + std::min(prevrow[j],thisrow[j-1]) );
        }
        std::swap(thisrow,prevrow);
    }
    return prevrow[bsize];
}


void BkTree::get_friends(std::string center, std::deque<std::string>& flv) {
    if( !m_root ) return ;
    std::queue< Node* > q;
    q.push( m_root );

    while( !q.empty() ) {
        Node *t = q.front(); 
        q.pop();
        if ( !t ) continue;

        size_t d = EditDistance( t->m_item, center );
        if( d == 1 ) { 
            if ( t->visited == false ) {
                flv.push_back(t->m_item);
                t->visited = true;
            }
        }
        Node *ch = t->m_firstChild;
        q.push(ch);
        while( ch ) {
            if( ch->m_distToParent >=  1 )
                q.push(ch);
            ch = ch->m_nextSibling;
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    BkTree *pDictionary = new BkTree();

    std::ifstream dictFile("word.list");
    std::string line; 
    if (dictFile.is_open()) {
        while (! dictFile.eof() ) {               
            std::getline (dictFile,line);
            if ( line.size()) {
                pDictionary->insert(line);
            }
        }
        dictFile.close();
    }
    std::deque<std::string>  flq;
    pDictionary->get_friends("aa", flq);
    int counter = 0;
    while ( !flq.empty()) {
        counter++;
        std::string nf = flq.front();
        flq.pop_front();
        pDictionary->get_friends(nf, flq);
    } 
    std::cout << counter << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any comments on improving the speed, or any other suitable data-structure.

Assume following is my dictionary.

```
aa
aah
aal
aam
aami
aamii
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

I am trying to find the `social network` of `aa` answer is `5`.

```
aa -> aah aal aam
aah -> aa, aal aam
aal -> aa, aah, aam
aam -> aa, aah, aal, aami
aami -> aam, aamii

ANSWER : -> aah + aal + aam + aami + aamii
```

Comment: I’ve never heard of the Levingston distance before and Google turns up pretty little but your `EditDistance` method implements the **Levenshtein distance**.

Comment: @Kerrek SB , this is not FB puzzle, I solved http://www.facebook.com/careers/puzzles.php?puzzle_id=17 in reasonable time, using the same DS.

Comment: Essentially, for each node, you're finding all its neighbours (friends) and then again finding all their neighbours. Finding all neighbours of a string with k neighbours isn't even an O(k) time operation in your implementation; it seems to be O(|dict|). It would be better to first find and store (preprocess) the graph of friends between the nodes, then given each string, simply find its neighbours and then report the union of their neighbour sets rather than finding them all over again. Depending of course, on the size of the dictionary — how big is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a read of [Fast and Easy Levenshtein distance using a Trie](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=114) for details of an efficient way of solving this.

In your example code, isn't a "friend of a friend" an edit distance of 2 (or 0)?  You can probably stop using a depth first search and just directly compare whether the Levenshtein distance is 0 or 2 (zero indicates that the edit is "undone" by the second relationship e.g. A -> B has an edit distance of 1, B -> C has an edit distance of 1 that exactly undoes the A -> B edit giving an edit distance of zero between A -> C).

This also seems related to the [word ladders puzzles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_ladder).  A great visualization of the explosion of variations is available [here](http://jkkramer.wordpress.com/2010/08/27/fun-with-clojure%C2%A0turning-cats-into-dogs-in-hanoi/).  I guess for your algorithm you want to find all paths between pairs of words that are of length 2?  Perhaps expressing it as a word ladders problems for all pairs will give you a new approach?

Comment: friend of a friend is not distance 2. If A has friends B,C,D ( with distance 1 ) then I am supposed to look for B,C,D also for distance with 1.

Comment: @Jeff Unfortunately not. Assume your dictionary only contains 'A' and 'B'. Then the fof of 'A' is 'A' itself but not 'B' (which has distance <= 2).

Comment: Since my code is working on small set of test case and giving me correct answers. I do not understand why does it take so much of time for large dictionary. Building a dictionary does not take more than 2.29 s on my ubuntu box.

Comment: @Howard, can you rule out friend of yourself and give another example?

Comment: @Howard, Updated the question with example.

Comment: @Jeff Ok, let me try: [A, AB, ABC, C]. Again, only ABC is friend of friend for A but neither AB or C which both have distance <= 2.

Comment: @Howard : Here is the what is expected in this case A-> AB
AB -> ABC and A->C so answer is 3.

Comment: @Howard, I see.  That's pretty complicated.  Perhaps the way the costs for edits can be altered to address this; it seems that deletions.